# How do I version Azure Functions so I can query at runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, system.reflection

I have an azure function that I want to report what version of the code it is running.  In other applications I am able to get this by running something of the nature:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

However I don't a) seem to have away of putting that data into the azure function (there is no assembly information button) or b) retrieving that information (the above code snippet always returns 1.0)

Is there a way (other than just putting in a configuration setting or private variable) to pull a standard version value from an Azure function via this mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are currently using .csx files from the Azure portal. If you instead switch to using Visual Studio and precompiled assemblies (which is generally recommended) the code you have above should work fine.

Specifically, use the following steps to change the version:

- Right click on the Project and choose Properties
- Go to 'Package'
- Change the Package version

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, but there isn't a place within the Azure Function to put the Assembly Version (button missing on right click > properties).  It works inside referenced DLLs, but not in the Azure Function itself.

Comment: Have you tried going to right click > properties > package and change the package number? I noticed that there isn't an assembly version by default, but once I changed it, the field was present in the .csproj file.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorMcMahon, I have updated the answer with these more detailed steps.

Comment: thanks so much; this looks to resolve this issue and be where that value is set; thanks again for the details.